# Counting characters, words, lines an paragraphs in C

Tags: c, io, count, words, getchar

I'm trying to count the characters, words, lines an paragraphs in C from the stdin.

something is not working and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int pCount=0, parCount=0, cCount=0, lCount=0;
    double prom=0;
    char c;
    int newln_cnt=0;
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){ 
        cCount++;
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\n':
                newln_cnt++;
                lCount++;
                if (newln_cnt == 2)
                {
                    parCount++;
                    newln_cnt = 0;
                }
                break;
            case ' ':
                pCount++;
                break;
        }               
    }
    prom = (cCount / pCount);
    printf("Total caracteres: %d \n", cCount);
    printf("Cantidad palabras: %d \n", pCount);
    printf("Cantidad líneas: %d \n", lCount);
    printf("Cantidad párrafos: %d \n", parCount);
    printf("Promedio longitud palabra: %f \n", prom);
    return 0;
}
```

it kinda works with the characters (it shows one less). but the rest is all bad.

Input:

> ```
> Oid, mortales, el grito sagrado:
> "Libertad, libertad, libertad!"
>
> Oid el ruido de rotas cadenas,
> ved en trono a la noble igualdad.
>
> Ya su trono dignisimo abrieron
> las Provincias Unidas del Sud
>
> y los libres del mundo responden:
> "Al gran pueblo argentino, salud!
> Al gran pueblo argentino, salud!"
>
> Y los libres del mundo responden:
> "Al gran pueblo argentino, salud!"
>
> Sean eternos los laureles
> que supimos conseguir,
> que supimos conseguir.
>
> Coronados de gloria vivamos...
> o juremos con gloria morir!,
> o juremos con gloria morir!,
>
> o juremos con gloria morir!
> ```

Expected Ouput:

```
Total caracteres: 558
Cantidad palabras: 87
Cantidad líneas: 25
Cantidad párrafos: 8
Promedio longitud palabra: 4.966
```

my ouput:

```
Total caracteres: 557
Cantidad palabras: 69
Cantidad líneas: 24
Cantidad párrafos: 12
Promedio longitud palabra: 8.000
```

The program counts the number of characters, words, lines and paragraphs (two consecutive '\n'). and the averge word length .

Comment: `char c;`should be `int c;`.

Comment: You never increment `cCount`. `pCount` is actually the number of spaces which is not quite the same as the number of words. And imagine what happens if you enter 3 lines without any spaces, what would `pcount` be then ?

Comment: There is some progress in your question, but your input sample is far too long for debugging.

Comment: I pasted it to a .txt and execute the program like cat text.txt | ./program

Comment: OK, now I get the same output as you. You really should consider testing and debugging your program with a shorter and simple input file. Maybe it's time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each your count conditions are wrong.
fix like follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    int pCount=0, parCount=0, cCount=0, lCount=0;//word, paragraph, character, line
    int abCount = 0;//alphabet 
    double prom=0;
    int c;//It should be int.
    char pprev = '\n', prev = '\n';

    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        ++cCount;
        if(isalpha(c))
            ++abCount;
        if(isspace(c)){
            if(c == '\n'){
                ++lCount;
            }
        } else if(isspace(prev)){//isspace(prev) && !isspace(c) : edge of top of word
            ++pCount;
            if(pprev == '\n' && prev == '\n'){//edge of top of paragraph
                ++parCount;
            }
        }
        pprev = prev;
        prev = c;
    }
    if(prev != '\n'){//If the file is not terminated by newline
        ++lCount;
    }

    prom = (double)abCount / pCount;//(cCount - spcCount - punctCount) / pCount
    printf("Total caracteres: %d \n", cCount);
    printf("Cantidad palabras: %d \n", pCount);
    printf("Cantidad lineas: %d \n", lCount);
    printf("Cantidad parrafos: %d \n", parCount);
    printf("Promedio longitud palabra: %.3f \n", prom);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be a count of the word to remove the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problem in your code:

1. Paragraphs count: you do not set `newln_cnt` to 0 if read character is different of `\n`. This will count one paragraph each time two `\n` are read.
2. Spaces count: you only consider `' '` characters, you may miss other white space characters like \t ou non breakable space. consider using `isspace()` function.
3. Mean line length: you divide two integers to get a float, consider casting:

   ```
   prom = (float)cCount / (flao)pCount;
   ```

My advice: Start with a short text (3 words per line, 5 lines) and a debugger.

Answer (score -2):

It didn't compile because of type conversion errors, but you can use floats for everything and it will compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double pCount=0, parCount=0, cCount=0, lCount=0;
    double prom=0;
    char c;
    int newln_cnt=0;
    while ((c=getchar())!=EOF){ 
        switch (c)
        {
            case '\n':
                newln_cnt++;
                lCount++;
                if (newln_cnt == 2)
                {
                    parCount++;
                    newln_cnt = 0;
                }
                break;
            case ' ':
                pCount++;
                break;
        }               
    }
    prom = (cCount / pCount);
    printf("Total caracteres: %f \n", cCount);
    printf("Cantidad palabras: %f \n", pCount);
    printf("Cantidad líneas: %f \n", lCount);
    printf("Cantidad párrafos: %f \n", parCount);
    printf("Promedio longitud palabra: %f \n", prom);
    return 0;
}
```

Now that the program compiles, you can adjust to whatever types are best for you program, you might even have a type of your own.

A famous program that works like your program is [wc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)) - word count and is part of the standard Unix libraries.

Comment: Why would using floating point types here be better than integers?

Comment: @dreamlax _"Promedio longitud palabra"_ means _average_

Comment: @Programmer400 _average word length_

Comment: @Programmer400: My point is `prom` can be assigned the average using `(double)cCount / pCount` without having to convert *everything* to floating point. There's seldom a need to have floating point types as counters.

Comment: @dreamlax Yes, I just wanted to compile the thing, now we can agree if we should have casts, which we probably should. I added a link to the `wc` program which is short and doesn't print the average AFAIK.